# Google Apps javascript interpreter failed with an array parameter in a user defined function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

This trivial function, written in the script editor of a Google Sheet, failed !

```
function Long(my_array)
{
  Logger.log(my_array.length)
}

 Long([1,2,3]); // => TypeError: Impossible to read property "length" from undefined.**
```

---

*Still same error with Google script interpreter, even  **without** executing the function call:*

**function** Long(my_array) {
  return my_array.length}

// => TypeError: Impossible to read proprerty "length" since undefined. line 2

*Of course, any correct  Javascript interpreter will not failed.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Google's script editor, the run operation will execute one of the functions defined in the script (a drop-down can be seen next to the *run* and *debug* buttons). The selected function must have been `Long` itself, which was called with no arguments.

Instead, just create a new function and select it before running:

```
function Long(my_array)
{
  Logger.log(my_array.length)
}


function myFunction() {
  Long([1,2,3,4]);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you are trying right now. And what do you mean with "any correct JavaScript interpreter would not have failed"? The problem here is that it's calling your function with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now, that the Google script editor run operation, can only execute a named  function without argument.

Comment: Indeed, all you have to do is put the code you want to run in a function. You may wish to mark the answer as accepted.